# ApiPlatform SerializeListener very slow

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

We're rewriting our API to use the excellent API-Platform library, but it's taking 6 seconds to return a small set of data, and 5 of those seconds are the APIPlatform SerializeListener.  Is there any way we can speeed that up?  It's a show-stopper.

[image: Symfony Profiler]

Comment: Metadata extraction is slow. Did you enable the metadata cache? ( https://api-platform.com/docs/core/performance#header )

Comment: I think that's the issue, thanks.  It appears that it caches automatically in production, but not in the development environment.

Comment: There is some discussion on this issue here: https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/653

With x-debug enabled, it's very, very slow.

Comment: @Federkun could please give more information about how to enable the metadata cache ?

Comment: @famas23 just install and enable APCu in your PHP. API Platform will take advantage of it automatically.

Comment: I have just installed APCu and I see no performance gain in development machine.

Comment: My suggestion - enable xdebug only when you need it)

Comment: I confirm, independently of api-platform, Xdebug makes loading very slow especially when "profile" and "trace" are enable, so follow advice of @Evgeny Ruban.